# how can I get child elements in angularjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I'm making a multi-select "drop-down" and I want to disable the category and style it differently in my "drop-down". so I got the select element and I want to make those children that are category disable. how can I get the children to do this.
so far I've done this:

```js
"use strict";

var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope, $http) {

  $scope.datas = [{
    "item": "South Korea",
    "category": "Asia",
    "flag": false
  }, {
    "item": "England",
    "category": "Europe",
    "flag": false
  }, {
    "item": "Japan",
    "category": "Asia",
    "flag": false
  }, {
    "item": "Denmark",
    "category": "Europe",
    "flag": false
  }, {
    "item": "North Korea",
    "category": "Asia",
    "flag": false
  }, {
    "item": "Geramany",
    "category": "Europe",
    "flag": false
  }, {
    "item": "China",
    "category": "Asia",
    "flag": false
  }, {
    "item": "Spain",
    "category": "Europe",
    "flag": false
  }, {
    "item": "India",
    "category": "Asia",
    "flag": false
  }, {
    "item": "Italy",
    "category": "Europe",
    "flag": false
  }, {
    "item": "Tailand",
    "category": "Asia",
    "flag": false
  }, {
    "item": "Portugal",
    "category": "Europe",
    "flag": false
  }];

  $scope.catCountainr = [];
  $scope.categorizedData = [];
  $scope.indexContainer = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < $scope.datas.length; i++) {
    if ($scope.catCountainr.indexOf($scope.datas[i].category) == -1) {
      $scope.catCountainr.push($scope.datas[i].category);
    }
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < $scope.catCountainr.length; i++) {
    $scope.categorizedData.push($scope.catCountainr[i]);
    $scope.indexContainer.push($scope.categorizedData.indexOf($scope.datas[i].category));
    for (var j = 0; j < $scope.datas.length; j++) {
      if ($scope.datas[j].category == $scope.catCountainr[i]) {
        $scope.categorizedData.push($scope.datas[j].item);
      }
    }
  }
  var select = angular.element(document.getElementById("select"));






});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.10/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div class="container">
    <form action="" class="">
      <div id="widgetContainer">
        <!--<input type="text" ng-click="openSelect()" class="input-control">
    <div id="selectContainer" ng-show="selectEnable">
     <div>{{selectedItems.toString()}}</div>
     <input type="text" id="searchField" ng-model="searchField" ng-change="filter()">
     <div id="listContainer">
      <ul id="innerContainer">
       <li ng-repeat="data in data2Show | orderBy: data.item" ng-model="data2show">
        <h4>{{data.category}}</h4>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-change="itemChecked(data)" name="select" ng-model="data.flag" ng-checked="isChecked(data)"> {{data.item}}
       </li>

       <div ng-show="dataLoading" ng-model="dataLoading">loading...</div>
       <li id="loadMore" ng-click="loadMore()">
        load more
       </li>

      </ul>
     </div>
    </div>-->

        <ul id="select">
          <li ng-repeat="key in categorizedData">{{ key }}</li>
        </ul>


      </div>
    </form>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

When I use `select.children()` it's not working

Is there any other way to get those children?
thank you in advance

Comment: basically you are asking for children before binding  I think so there is no children there.

Comment: so how should I do this?

Comment: Try keeping your code in $timeout

Comment: can I ask you "WHY"? why you want to get the elements instead of doing everything with model binding etc. You could for example use ng-class to disable elemts. right?

Comment: then how can I for example make the background of child number 0 and 7 different than other children and make those two disabled?

Comment: use $index for that ? https://codepen.io/bunny1985/pen/LrLpob

Comment: can you please explain. all I did with $index is in ng-repeat I used "as $index" how can I style specific $index differently?

Comment: take a look at this code pen https://codepen.io/bunny1985/pen/LrLpob

Comment: indexContainer contains the index of the items that I want to disable so I did this: ng-class="{categoryStyler: $index == indexContainer[$index]}" so how should I change it to work? and also other than style how can I make that content disabled so the user can't select it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.catCountainr.length; i++) {
    $scope.categorizedData.push({
      item: $scope.catCountainr[i],
      isDisabled: true
    });
    $scope.indexContainer.push($scope.categorizedData.indexOf($scope.datas[i].category));
    for (var j = 0; j < $scope.datas.length; j++) {
      if ($scope.datas[j].category == $scope.catCountainr[i]) {
        $scope.categorizedData.push({
          item: $scope.datas[j].item,
          isDisabled: false
        });
      }
    }
  }


 <ul id="select">
          <li ng-repeat="data in categorizedData" ng-class="{'diffColor': data.isDisabled}">{{ data.item }}</li>
        </ul>

.diffColor {
    background-color: wheat;
    pointer-events: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

```js
"use strict";

var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope, $http) {

  $scope.datas = [{
    "item": "South Korea",
    "category": "Asia",
    "flag": false
  }, {
    "item": "England",
    "category": "Europe",
    "flag": false
  }, {
    "item": "Japan",
    "category": "Asia",
    "flag": false
  }, {
    "item": "Denmark",
    "category": "Europe",
    "flag": false
  }, {
    "item": "North Korea",
    "category": "Asia",
    "flag": false
  }, {
    "item": "Geramany",
    "category": "Europe",
    "flag": false
  }, {
    "item": "China",
    "category": "Asia",
    "flag": false
  }, {
    "item": "Spain",
    "category": "Europe",
    "flag": false
  }, {
    "item": "India",
    "category": "Asia",
    "flag": false
  }, {
    "item": "Italy",
    "category": "Europe",
    "flag": false
  }, {
    "item": "Tailand",
    "category": "Asia",
    "flag": false
  }, {
    "item": "Portugal",
    "category": "Europe",
    "flag": false
  }];

  $scope.catCountainr = [];
  $scope.categorizedData = [];
  $scope.indexContainer = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < $scope.datas.length; i++) {
    if ($scope.catCountainr.indexOf($scope.datas[i].category) == -1) {
      $scope.catCountainr.push($scope.datas[i].category);
    }
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < $scope.catCountainr.length; i++) {
    $scope.categorizedData.push({
      item: $scope.catCountainr[i],
      isDisabled: true
    });
    $scope.indexContainer.push($scope.categorizedData.indexOf($scope.datas[i].category));
    for (var j = 0; j < $scope.datas.length; j++) {
      if ($scope.datas[j].category == $scope.catCountainr[i]) {
        $scope.categorizedData.push({
          item: $scope.datas[j].item,
          isDisabled: false
        });
      }
    }
  }

});
```

```css
.diffColor {
  background-color: wheat;
  pointer-events: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.10/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div class="container">
    <form action="" class="">
      <div id="widgetContainer">
        <!--<input type="text" ng-click="openSelect()" class="input-control">
    <div id="selectContainer" ng-show="selectEnable">
     <div>{{selectedItems.toString()}}</div>
     <input type="text" id="searchField" ng-model="searchField" ng-change="filter()">
     <div id="listContainer">
      <ul id="innerContainer">
       <li ng-repeat="data in data2Show | orderBy: data.item" ng-model="data2show">
        <h4>{{data.category}}</h4>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-change="itemChecked(data)" name="select" ng-model="data.flag" ng-checked="isChecked(data)"> {{data.item}}
       </li>

       <div ng-show="dataLoading" ng-model="dataLoading">loading...</div>
       <li id="loadMore" ng-click="loadMore()">
        load more
       </li>

      </ul>
     </div>
    </div>-->

        <ul id="select">
          <li ng-repeat="data in categorizedData" ng-class="{'diffColor': data.isDisabled}">{{ data.item }}</li>
        </ul>


      </div>
    </form>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**2nd Answer**

A slightly different approach then your js, but it seemed better to me so I have added. Please look into updated JS and HTML code as well.

```js
"use strict";

var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope, $http) {

  $scope.datas = [{
    "item": "South Korea",
    "category": "Asia",
    "flag": false
  }, {
    "item": "England",
    "category": "Europe",
    "flag": false
  }, {
    "item": "Japan",
    "category": "Asia",
    "flag": false
  }, {
    "item": "Denmark",
    "category": "Europe",
    "flag": false
  }, {
    "item": "North Korea",
    "category": "Asia",
    "flag": false
  }, {
    "item": "Geramany",
    "category": "Europe",
    "flag": false
  }, {
    "item": "China",
    "category": "Asia",
    "flag": false
  }, {
    "item": "Spain",
    "category": "Europe",
    "flag": false
  }, {
    "item": "India",
    "category": "Asia",
    "flag": false
  }, {
    "item": "Italy",
    "category": "Europe",
    "flag": false
  }, {
    "item": "Tailand",
    "category": "Asia",
    "flag": false
  }, {
    "item": "Portugal",
    "category": "Europe",
    "flag": false
  }];

  $scope.catCountainr = [];
  $scope.categorizedData = [];
  $scope.indexContainer = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < $scope.datas.length; i++) {
    if ($scope.catCountainr.indexOf($scope.datas[i].category) == -1) {
      $scope.catCountainr.push($scope.datas[i].category);
    }
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < $scope.catCountainr.length; i++) {
    $scope.categorizedData.push({
      item: $scope.catCountainr[i],
      isDisabled: true,
      items: []
    });
    for (var j = 0; j < $scope.datas.length; j++) {
      if ($scope.datas[j].category == $scope.catCountainr[i]) {
        $scope.categorizedData[i].items.push({
          item: $scope.datas[j].item
        });
      }
    }
  }

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.10/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div class="container">
    <form action="" class="">
      <div id="widgetContainer">
        <!--<input type="text" ng-click="openSelect()" class="input-control">
    <div id="selectContainer" ng-show="selectEnable">
     <div>{{selectedItems.toString()}}</div>
     <input type="text" id="searchField" ng-model="searchField" ng-change="filter()">
     <div id="listContainer">
      <ul id="innerContainer">
       <li ng-repeat="data in data2Show | orderBy: data.item" ng-model="data2show">
        <h4>{{data.category}}</h4>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-change="itemChecked(data)" name="select" ng-model="data.flag" ng-checked="isChecked(data)"> {{data.item}}
       </li>

       <div ng-show="dataLoading" ng-model="dataLoading">loading...</div>
       <li id="loadMore" ng-click="loadMore()">
        load more
       </li>

      </ul>
     </div>
    </div>-->

        <ul id="select">
          <li ng-repeat="data in categorizedData" class="isDisabled">{{data.item }}
            <ul ng-if="data.items && data.items.length > 0">
              <li ng-repeat="itemVar in data.items" class="isDisabled">{{itemVar.item }}</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>


      </div>
    </form>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thx but this code works only if I know the categories index and want to hard-code it but I want it to be dynamic